Which schema / table structure should I use to back up Google Analytics (UA) data to BigQuery?
We've written a JAVA application that pulls data from the Google Analytics API and pushes all client data into this BigQuery table (see current schema).  We are then using Materialized views in our individual client tables in BigQuery.
existing schema
We have about 50 UA properties that we are looking to backup to BigQuery.
We have one client that was on 360 and they had been running the UA to BigQuery connector for a few years and this is the schema that connector ended up creating (basically a single table).
I've created a sheet that shows all of the groups, dimensions, metrics and the associated scope for UA.  I wasn't able to find a definitive list of field names with their scope so I had to guess on many of them.
I am wondering if it is better to store the data in BigQuery into 4 tables based on the User, Session, Hit and Product scope or if it is better to go for a single table structure like the UA connector used to structure the data or if there is an alternative method.
I haven't tried anything yet other than what we've already built in Java.  I am just trying to get some advice on what the best direction we could take from here would be.

BigQuery best practices say to use nested and repeated fields to denormalize data storage and increase query performance.
This is beacause denormalization is a common strategy for increasing read performance for relational datasets that were previously normalized. The recommended way to denormalize data in BigQuery is to use nested and repeated fields.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-nested?hl=en

Thank you for your comment.  Would you advocate for a structure like this?
Example Nested Structure:
User Table:.

User-level information (e.g., userId, userType).
Nested fields for sessions and hits.

Session Table:.

Session-level information (e.g., sessionId, sessionCount).
Nested fields for hits.

Hit Table:.
Hit-level information (e.g., hitId, hitType).
Nested fields for product details if applicable.


Just to replicare BigQuery Export for GA4 structure (or for UA 360)

For UA, not for GA4. The primary purpose is to come up with a good method for backing up UA data before it is gone.

It is the same (similar), each row is a session with nested data based on hit (pageview, event, transaction, ...). You can see the database structure in the BigQuery Export for UA360.

Based on @michele's feedback I am thinking we break down the schema into three main tables: Users, Sessions, and Hits, using nested and repeated fields to optimize for performance and simplicity.  Here is an idea of what that could look like.
Detailed Schema Design

Users Table: The Users table contains user-level information and nests session data.

Schema:

userId: STRING
userType: STRING
sessions: RECORD (repeated)

sessionId: STRING
sessionCount: INTEGER
visitNumber: INTEGER
visitStartTime: TIMESTAMP
date: DATE
hits: RECORD (repeated)
hitId: STRING
hitType: STRING
pagePath: STRING
eventCategory: STRING
eventAction: STRING
eventLabel: STRING
product: RECORD (repeated)
productId: STRING
productName: STRING
productCategory: STRING
productRevenue: FLOAT




Sessions Table: The Sessions table contains session-level information and nests hit data.

Schema:

sessionId: STRING
userId: STRING
sessionCount: INTEGER
visitNumber: INTEGER
visitStartTime: TIMESTAMP
date: DATE
hits: RECORD (repeated)

hitId: STRING
hitType: STRING
pagePath: STRING
eventCategory: STRING
eventAction: STRING
eventLabel: STRING
product: RECORD (repeated)
productId: STRING
productName: STRING
productCategory: STRING
productRevenue: FLOAT




Hits Table: The Hits table contains detailed hit-level information and nests product data.

Schema:

hitId: STRING
sessionId: STRING
userId: STRING
hitType: STRING
pagePath: STRING
eventCategory: STRING
eventAction: STRING
eventLabel: STRING
product: RECORD (repeated)

productId: STRING
productName: STRING
productCategory: STRING
productRevenue: FLOAT



